# Markov chains derivation for absorbing states

Tags: probability, markov-process

I am given that the probability to reach a specific absorbing state $s$, from states 1, ..., M as $a_1, \cdots, a_M$, which are unique solutions to equations $a_s = 1$, $a_0 = 0$ for all absorbing states such that $i \neq s$, and $a_i = \sum_i^M a_j p_{ij}$ for all transient states $i$.

Can someone show me how this summation is derived. It looks like the law of total probability, by conditioning on the next states reachable from $i$. But it looks like a different kind of law of total probability (LOTP) that what I'm used to seeing.

Usually when I see LOTP, it's something like this:
$$
P(A) = \sum_k P(A, B_k) = \sum_k P(A | B_k) P(B_k).
$$

For the Markov chain probability $a_i$, say $i=1, M=2$, we have

$$
a_1 = p_{11}a_1 + p_{12}a2 \\
$$

Note that
$$
p_{11} = P(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_{n} = 1) \\
p_{12} = P(X_{n+1} = 2 | X_{n} = 1) \\
$$

Is this an application of LOTP?

Answer (score 0):

A minor issue first, but one which may have caused you confusion: the lower index in your first sum should be 1, not $i$; and in the "LOTP" equation, the notation $P(A\cap B_k)$ would also be clearer than $P(A, B_k)$.

Yes, the result does use the LOTP. The key observation that allows to connect the generic LOTP equation and your problem at hand is that the index $i$ is "built into" the probability $P$ from the LOTP (so that $P$ may itself be regarded as a conditional probability). That is, if $B_k$ is the probability of going to state $k$ in one step, then $P(B_k)$ is actually the probability of going from $i$ to $k$ in one step, thus corresponding to $p_{ik}$. That the second factor in the equation that you wish to prove is just $a_j$ is due to the Markov property.